# onActivityResult() in fragment always receiving null Intent

Tags: android

I have following workflow in my code. I have `fragment A` which starts a new `activity B` using startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode). Activity B has a fragment say `fragment C` which contains a listview (its adapter has an arraylist) and an edittext below to add new values into the listview.

I intend to send data back to `fragment A`. I have implemented an interface in the `fragment C` which is called in onPause() method of the same fragment.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OnSubtaskExitListener onSubtaskExitListener = (OnSubtaskExitListener) getSherlockActivity();
    onSubtaskExitListener.onExit(Subtasks);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Subtasks is the updated arraylist on adding new item from add button in edit text.

I have implemented this interface in `activity B` which contains the fragment C.

```
@Override
public void onExit(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subtasks) {
....
intent.putExtra("ResultArray", stringArray);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Note that startActivityForResult was called in fragment A. Therefore, setResult has been used.

**The problem**: In the `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` of fragment A, Intent data is always null. I have used android.util.Log in the onExit method in activity B to see if data being sent in put extra is null e.g. `Log.d("Array Result", stringArray[0].toString());` But onActivityResult() is always getting data null.

Please help me find the bug. Thanks :)

Comment: did you check if the code in `onExit()` is ever called?

Comment: yes. I have used Log to check that. It's perfectly okay upto setResult().

Comment: Does Activity A also override `onActivityResult()`? If so read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6147884/1267661).

Comment: Actually onActivityResult() is getting called. The Intent data argument in this method is null which I have ensured is not null when using the method setResult in activity B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot set activity result after `onPause()` has been called. Setting activity result in `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` will probably always give you null in `onActivityResult()`.

I don't know why you want to call `setResult()` in `onPause()` method but maybe you could move it to `onBackPressed()` or `onKeyDown()` method. This should resolved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I moved setResult to a menu item.

Comment: I had a similar problem even though I've implemented setResult() and onActivityResult() a 100 times. My setResult() was in onBackPressed() so I was stumped why my onActivityResult() received a null intent. It turned out that called setResult() after the super.onBackPressed() call. Moving super.onBackPressed() to the end of the function solved the issue.